# Reading/Converting incorrect value through data from serial port

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, serial-port, pyserial

I am doing a ser.read(), to read 16 bytes from a Microcontroller.

```
rxbuf_before_tag = ser.read(16)
print(rxbuf_before_tag)
rxbuf = ' '.join([hex(i) for i in rxbuf_before_tag]).split()
print(rxbuf)
```

I get the output as a bytearray:

```
b'G\x1a\x00\xc0\x8er\x00\xc0\x14\xff\xfd\xd5+\x19\xc3\x82'
```

What I get on the logical analyzer is this:

```
0x47 0x1A 0x00 0x00 0x92 0x8E 0x72 0x00 0xC0 0x14 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x75 0xA5 0x46
```

When I do the join operation as in the code above I get 
0x47 0x1a 0x0 0x92 0x8e 0x72 0xfe 0x58 0x85 0xfd 0xfd 0x2b 0x65 0xc3 0x4 0x4

Is the `ser.read()` reading wrong? Is my join operation faulty? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Added some code formatting to make question more readable.

Comment: I just noticed, if you look at all the bytes in the bytearray I am reading more than a byte. e.g. 8er. I wonder why. Is ser.read() effecient?

Comment: Can you post the intended output? Not too familiar with what you're trying to do so that might give people more context.

Comment: @Nikhil The intended output is the output from the logical analyzer(posting it again here: 0x47 0x1A 0x00 0x00 0x92 0x8E 0x72 0x00 0xC0 0x14 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x75 0xA5 0x46). I am reading data from a microcontroller via the serial port. The data on the logical analzer which is correct is as posted. Although ser.read() from pyserial module gives the byte array as above, which after the join split operation gives a different set of hex values.